# Need a REST api which will give the current time as output when provided with country/city name

Tags: rest

I am looking for a REST api which will provide me the city/country time and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GenoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) has a RESTful web service API which can give you the timezone of a point `P` in lat/lon. Maybe this is a good point to start..